# Parsing JSON Data in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON data from the Google Civic Information API with Swift 3 and keep running into trouble.

This is the code that I have now for my parseData function:

```
private func parseData(JSONData: Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]

        if let officials: Any = readableJSON["officials"] as? [String : Any] {

            for official in officials as? [String : Any] {

                let name = official["name"] as? String

                if let address = official["address"] as? [String : String] {

                    let line1 = address["line1"] as? String
                    let line2 = address["line2"] as? String
                    let line3 = address["line3"] as? String
                    let city = address["city"] as? String
                    let state = address["state"] as? String
                    let zipCode = address["zip"] as? String

                }

                let party = official["party"] as? String
                let phones = official["phones"] as? [String: Any]
                let urls = official["urls"] as? [String : Any]
                let photoURL = official["photoUrl"] as? String
                let emails = official["emails"] as? [String : Any]

                if let channels = official["channels"] as? [String : Any] {

                    for j in 0..<channels.count {

                        let channel = channels[j] as? [String : Any]
                        let type = channel["type"] as String
                        let id = channel["type"] as String

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { print(error) }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Keep running into what trouble exactly? Compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected results? Computer on fire?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let officials: Any = readableJSON["officials"] as? [String : Any] {

    for official in officials as? [String : Any] {
```

You are trying to loop over an object of type `Any`. Your casting properly on the right side, but then overriding it with a less specific type on the left. You can omit the left side type altogether, as Swift's type inference will know you are getting `[String : Any]?` from the right side.